# How to display API Gateway Data using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am new to JavaScript and I am developing a Website Hit Counter using DynamoDB, Lambda, and API Gateway. Each time a user hits my website, Lambda updates my DynamoDB table and increments it by 1. My goal is to display this updated number on my website but I am having trouble. This is my JavaScript code thus far,

```
<div>
    <p style = "text-align: center;">
    You are visitor # <span id="VisitorCounter"></span>
    <script>
fetch('https://6ka4boms3b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Visits/visitornumber', {
  method: 'GET', 
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
  },

})  
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
    </script>
    </p>
</div>
```

So far, my website only says "You are visitor # (blank)" and I get a SyntaxError on this line ".then(response => response.json())"

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `then(response => response.json())` on the same line as `fetch`, like this:

```
fetch(...
...
...).then(...)
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I still get a syntax error called unexpected end of input